# #autocomplete_path in form creating JS error

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am trying to use #autocomplete_path in my text field. But its showing error message. Same problem happening while using AHAH also.

Code :

```
 $form['test_module']['user_name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield', 
'#title' => t('Name of user'),
'#name' => 'user_name', 
'#required' => TRUE, 
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'inputtext'), 
'#id' => 'forminput_fn',
'#default_value' => 'User Name',
'#autocomplete_path' => 'user/autocomplete', 
);
```

The alert box having the following error,

> An error occurred. http://localhost/drupal6/user/autocomplete Array ( [0] => [Home](/drupal6/) ) { "admin": "admin" }

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact issue. Its my mistake. I gave print in drupal hook_init() function.
The auto complete will convert the output to JSON before that display. If we print any array in hook_init() that will add to your actual responce. So that will be a invalid format to JS. so JS can't parse correct response.

Thanks.